# Зачем в Java дженерик ? extends Number, когда можно просто Number

Tags: java, generics

Например есть метод:

```
public static Double sum(List<? extends Number> numList) {...}
```

Вместо него с тем же успехом можно использовать:

```
public static Double sum(List<Number> numList){...}
```

И какой профит от `<? extends Number>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если есть функция

```
public static Double sum(List<? extends Number> numList) {
    return numList.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
            .reduce((left, right) -> left + right)
            .getAsDouble();
}
```

то в нее можно передавать лист любых `Number`-ов (`Double`, `Long` итд).
Если же параметр будет просто `List<Number>`, то лист `Double`-ов передать нельзя.